# How to navigate to another Page from button's Clicked event and pass listview's ItemSelected as argument?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm writing an app for Android in Xamarin Forms. I want to navigate the user from one page to another, when user clicks an "EditList" button (middle one), but at the same time I want to pass an argument of specific type: "ShoppingList", which I get from ListView's ItemSelected event in order to display it's contents on the next Page.

The problem is - the only way I can get that value is when the item in listview is clicked. How can I get that listview item clicked value from within the button, without having to click on the listview item beforehand?

**How it looks**

Also here's the Page for reference:
[image: ListView with ShoppingList items]

I'm using Navigation.PushAsync(), where I also pass a ShoppingListDetailViewModel and inject the item from SelectedItem

**OnItemSelected**

Here is ListView's OnItemSelected event handler for ItemSelected event:

```
        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var item = args.SelectedItem as ShoppingList;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingListDetailPage(new ShoppingListDetailViewModel(item)));

            // Manually deselect item.
            ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

(ItemsListView is my ListView's name defined in XAML like that x:Name="ItemsListView")

I've tried to make Command which would maybe pass a Shopping List object through Command parameter but I got confused with all that, and I think that there must be simpler solution for doing this which I just can't see.

**XAML**

This is my XAML Page with the ListView and button inside it:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingLists}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label  Text="{Binding BodyHighlight}" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ImageButton Grid.Column="0"
                                                 Source="delete.png"> 
                                    </ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton 
                                        Grid.Column="1" 
                                        Source="edit.png"
                                        Clicked="EditListButton_Clicked">
                                     </ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton 
                                        Grid.Column="2" 
                                        Source="send.png" >
                                    </ImageButton>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get that listview item clicked value from within the button, without having to click on the listview item beforehand?

**Solution One:**

Xaml code no change,and `EditListButton_Clicked` as follow:

```
public void EditListButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
 ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
 var item = btn.BindingContext as ShoppingList;
 if (item == null) return;
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingListDetailPage(new ShoppingListDetailViewModel(item)));
}
```

**Solution Two:**

Said as jason, add `CommandParameter` to `ImageButton` as follow:

```
<ImageButton  Grid.Column="1" Source="edit.png" Clicked="EditListButton_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}>
```

Then in `EditListButton_Clicked` is:

```
public void EditListButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
  ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
  var item = (ShoppingList)btn.CommandParameter;
  if (item == null) return;
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingListDetailPage(new ShoppingListDetailViewModel(item)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Although I have one more question. How did you know that you had to do those two casts (especially to btn.Binding Context) to get a hold of that ListView item? I have problem with understanding that.

Comment: @Tomasz Yeah,This is a bit of understanding of BindingContext. If your ListView's ItemSource is bound to ShoppingLists, then each ViewCell is bound to a ShoppingList, ViewCell.
Each element in the binding is a ShoppingList, so this time the Button is bound to the ShoppingList. When the BindingContext is used much more in the project, you can understand its role.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#data-bindings

Answer (score 1):

assign the value of the current item in the list to the Button's CommandParameter

```
<ImageButton Grid.Column="1" Source="edit.png" 
  Clicked="EditListButton_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

then in your handler

```
public void EditListButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
  ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

  var item = (ShoppingList)btn.CommandParameter;

  if (item == null) return;

  await Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingListDetailPage(new ShoppingListDetailViewModel(item)));

}
```